# Weird output in catalina.out Tomcat9

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat9

I'm using Tomcat9 as a server and I'm using `Catalina.out` as my logger output  `"System.out"` and `"System.error"` . I don't know every time I open and refresh the Catalina.out file, it gives out the weird output (as shown in picture below) and this output is keep increasing until more than million length. It makes slow loading to open the Catalina.out file. After this weird thing loaded, the logger output that I needed will be at the bottom of those things.

Opened `Catalina.out` via notepad++ will have below output :

[image]

I expect the output doesn't give this weird annoying output.

Comment: Are you sure encoding is `ANSI`?

Comment: If there were characters beside NUL (`\u0000`) then I would assume UTF-16 interpreted as single byte encoding (ANSI). In NotePad++ try encodings UCS-2 little and big endian.

Comment: I try out. But now I figured out that even I'm using different platform to open Catalina.out file , it still showing weird output. Means that, there is something problem with my logging configuration in Tomcat9. Not the notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that weird output will only happens when I delete all the Startup logger in Catalina.out.

Example of Startup logger :

.
.
{some logger}
08-Aug-2019 15:15:22.692 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [33,192] milliseconds

If I just leave it, it will not give the weird output again.
So, I will close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need some formatting here. Just follow these steps.

1. Open your file in Notepad++
2. Type Control-A (select all)
3. Type Control-H (replace) In 'Find What' type '\x00'
4. In 'Replace With' leave BLANK In 'Search Mode' Selected 'Extended'
5. Then Click on 'Replace All'

Comment: Basically I can manually delete it and don't need to use your step. Normally I will delete the NULNUL output and keep my logger output ("System.out") when I'm doing my work.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the encoding of the log is wrong.
May be, you should check the property of the log writing of Apache Tomcat.

(see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html)

Hope, it should help you.